# How to store custom ggplot aliases as `list` objects in .R script and source them along required label vectors

Tags: r, ggplot2, vector

I want to streamline my work with `ggplot2` given certain settings I repeat across plots. To this end, I want to:

1. set aliases for those `ggplot2` settings (assigned to individual `list` objects)
2. store them all in an `.R` script
3. `source()` the `.R` script
4. call the aliases when creating a plot with `ggplot`

However, this workflow fails when I set aliases for ggplot functions that call vectors. For example, `scale_x_discrete()` has an argument called `labels`, which takes a character vector of strings. This vector can be set in-place (e.g., `scale_x_discrete(labels = c("a", "b", "c"))`) or otherwise call a vector object stored in the environment:

```r
labels_for_x <- c("a", "b", "c")

scale_x_discrete(labels = labels_for_x)
```

Therefore, my problem happens when I want to set an "alias" for a ggplot function that relies on an additional, separate vector.

### Demonstrating the problem with example

**Step 1 -- set alias for `scale_x_discrete` in a new `.R` script**

```r
library(tidyverse)

mygg_scale_x_relabel <-
  scale_x_discrete() %>%
  list
```

Works!
But what if:

```r
mygg_scale_x_relabel <-
  scale_x_discrete(labels = labels_for_barplot) %>%
  list
```

> Error in check_breaks_labels(breaks, labels) :    object
> 'labels_for_barplot' not found

So I can do:

```r
labels_for_barplot <- c()

mygg_scale_x_relabel <-
  scale_x_discrete(labels = labels_for_barplot) %>%
  list
```

And this runs OK.

---

**Step 2 -- open a *new* `.R`/`.Rmd` script and source the previous `.R` script with alias**

```r
source(file = ...)
```

---

**Step 3 -- in the new script, generate a bar plot**

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(trt = c("col_1", "col_2", "col_3"), outcome = c(2.3, 1.9, 3.2))

p <-
  ggplot(df, aes(trt, outcome)) +
  geom_col()

p
```

[image: orig_lanels]

---

**Step 4 -- (PROBLEM HAPPENS HERE) -- call the `scale_x_discrete` alias**

```r
labels_for_barplot <- c(col_1 = "new_lab_col_1",
                        col_2 = "new_lab_col_2",
                        col_3 = "new_lab_col_3")

p +
  mygg_scale_x_relabel
```

[image: no_labels]
<----- You can see here that all x labels are now gone! 
 
 This is because I've set `labels_for_barplot <- c()` (meaning, an empty vector) in my aliases script. But why this cannot be overridden with an updated vector assignment after script is sourced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign a value to `mygg_scale_x_relabel`, it gets set straight away with the values it has. It won't change when `labels_for_barplot` changes.

The best way to do what you want is with a function. The function won't evaluate until you call it.

```
mygg_scale_x_relabel <- function(labels_for_barplot) {
  scale_x_discrete(labels = labels_for_barplot) %>%
  list()
}

labels_for_barplot <- c(col_1 = "new_lab_col_1",
                        col_2 = "new_lab_col_2",
                        col_3 = "new_lab_col_3")

p +
  mygg_scale_x_relabel(labels_for_barplot)
```

[image: p1]

However, if you *really* wanted the syntax you've described, you can use active bindings. This is not the way things should be done generally, though.

```
rlang::env_bind_active(
  rlang::global_env(),
  mygg_scale_x_relabel = function() scale_x_discrete(labels = labels_for_barplot) %>% list()
)

labels_for_barplot <- c(col_1 = "new_lab_col_1",
                        col_2 = "new_lab_col_2",
                        col_3 = "new_lab_col_3")

p + mygg_scale_x_relabel
```

[image: p2]

```
labels_for_barplot <- c(col_1 = "a",
                        col_2 = "b",
                        col_3 = "c")

p + mygg_scale_x_relabel
```

[image: p3]